# Tagged Hooks not recognized in a particular package

Tags: groovy, cucumber, bdd

I have created a gradle project which uses cucumber and geb. My programming language is groovy. 
All my steps files are located at com.bada.bada.bada.cucumber.step

```
Feature:
    User usecases

    @Login
    Scenario: Login User to website
        Given I am on the mywebsite
        And I log in with a valid username and a valid password
        When I see profile
        Then I can see my profile image
```

and my Hook code is

```
this.metaClass.mixin(cucumber.api.groovy.Hooks)
this.metaClass.mixin(cucumber.api.groovy.EN)

Before("@Login") {
    // Go nuts
}
```

If the definition of hook is in com.bada.bada.bada.cucumber.step.SomefileSteps.groovy, then the hook is recognised but if it exists in com.bada.bada.bada.cucumber.hooks.SomeHooks.groovy then it is not.

Why is this an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glue directories were not updated. Updating those fixed the issue.